# Xcode 14.3.1 - No such module

Tags: swift, xcode, xcode14.3

I have a project that was working perfectly, but after updating XCode to 14.3, I can't generate the build anymore.

In fact, now it gives the error "No such module Result".

I've already performed several activities such as updating Xcode, cleaning the build folder, applying `pod deintegrate`, updating cocoapods and I don't get results.

[image]

Importantly, as of Xcode 14.3 beta there is no longer a Rosetta architecture option, so I believe it is something related to the Apple Silicon architecture.

Comment: Without knowing what the library is, how it's added, etc, this is likely impossible to debug here. Ideally, you'd include a [mre]

Answer (score 0):

Try to upgrade the pod to

```
pod 'Result', '~> 5.0.0'
```

or try to add this ad the end of podfile and make a clean + pod install + build

```
post_install do |installer|
    installer.generated_projects.each do |project|
          project.targets.each do |target|
              target.build_configurations.each do |config|
                  config.build_settings['IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET'] = '11.0'
               end
          end
   end
end
```

or try to switch to xcode 13 compatible project document

[image]

Answer (score 0):

on my case i just added this line

```
config.build_settings['ONLY_ACTIVE_ARCH'] = 'NO'
```

to `Podfile`

```
post_install do |installer|
installer.generated_projects.each do |project|
      project.targets.each do |target|
          target.build_configurations.each do |config|
              config.build_settings['ONLY_ACTIVE_ARCH'] = 'NO'
              config.build_settings['IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET'] = '11.0'
           end
      end
   end
end
```

and its working both xcode 14.3.1 and 14.2,

Good luck!